# Extending E3 Visa to Travel Visa

Tags: visas, usa

My Girlfriend is in the USA on an E3 work visa which ends in April. She plans on moving back to Australia when the E3 Visa ends but she needs to stay here to see The Rolling Stones in May!! So my question is.. can she just apply for a travel visa while she is already In the country and stay longer without having to go back to Australia? And how would she go about extending her stay a month or two? She will no longer be working after the E3 ends .

Comment: What is the date on her I-94?

Comment: No she cannot apply for a **visa** within the country.`If your plans change while in the United States (for example, you marry a U.S. citizen or receive an offer of employment), you may be able to request a change in your nonimmigrant status to another category through U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). See Change My Nonimmigrant Status on the USCIS website to learn more.`

Comment: Please don't just write "the country" and assume that everybody will know which country you're talking about. There are about 200 countries in the world.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is pretty clear from the sentence structure that the OP means the country he is already in; i.e. the USA.

Comment: @ajd Yes, it's obvious that it means "The country that I'm in at the moment." However, the only way you could infer that it's the USA is by knowing what an E3 visa is and guessing that no other country has one of those. The tag "USA" was added later. There is no justification at all for assuming that everyone will figure out where you're from. It needs to be explicitly stated.

Comment: oh sorry, I only read the version after your edit that made it start with "My girlfriend is in the USA".